# Mysql dump multiple records

Tags: mysql

I want to dump the following condition

```
mysqldump --opt --user=AdminUser --password=AdminPassword myDB account  --where=account_id IN ('211269','212366','211104')
```

I try run this and get an error

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(
```

Any idea how do I dump record of 211269,212366,211104 in 1 single cmd line.

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escaping the string as follows to avoid bash interpretation:

```
mysqldump --opt --user=AdminUser --password=AdminPassword myDB \
account  --where=account_id IN \('211269','212366','211104'\)
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition has to be enclosed with quotes or escpe, otherwise the cli interpreter will parse the '(' as commands instead of part of the condition:

```
mysqldump --opt --user=AdminUser --password=AdminPassword myDB account\
--where='account_id IN ("211269","212366","211104")'
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.